# Constant name of iterm2 tab

Tags: macos, iterm2, iterm

I can change the title of terminal tabs in iTerm2 by pressing CMD-I and setting some name. But as soon as I open e.g. vim and close it, tab name is reset to what my prompt says, instead of being "sticky".
Is it possible to force the tab name so it does not change?